# Haskell function with type (num -> num) -> num

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I am struggling with an exercise in R. Bird's functional programming book that asks for an example of a function with type (num -> num) -> num

The best I can come up with is a polymorphic type

```
func1 f = f 3
:t func1
func1 :: Num t1 => (t1 -> t2) -> t2
```

The problem I am having is that I can't specify the return type of f, so the type remains (num -> t2) -> t2.

My attempt to force the return type of f is as follows:

```
square x = x * x
:t func1 square
func1 square :: Num t2 => t2 -> t2
```

Because of course if I try to find the type of func1 ∘ square it will just be num -> num

Comment: It really helps to be precise. `(Num a) => (a -> a) -> a` is a very different type than `(num -> num) -> num`. Classes are not types. Instances are not subtypes. And very importantly, the former type has a lot of total implementations, while the latter has only partial implementations.

Comment: `fix f = let x = f x in x` has type `(a -> a) -> a` [fix](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.5/base-4.10.1.0/Data-Function.html#v:fix)

Comment: @Carl The book uses the exact wording (num -> num) -> num. I guess the question is can I define a function of type Num a => (a -> a) -> a

Comment: @freestyle and that's a partial function. Sometimes useful, but there are total inputs for which it never returns.

Comment: @Carl Thanks, I know.

Comment: @samlu1999 well, then, it's important to know exactly what was meant. Naming a type variable `num` is very leading. Is Bird using a non-standard Haskell-like language, or does he mean `(a -> a) -> a`? Bird is fully capable of meaning either, and I don't know what that book does.

Comment: @Carl I only know a book by Bird and Wadler and it definitely uses a non-Haskell.

Comment: It looks like you are using some version of [this book](https://usi-pl.github.io/lc/sp-2015/doc/Bird_Wadler.%20Introduction%20to%20Functional%20Programming.1ed.pdf) by Bird and Wadler. It doesn't use Haskell but some ad-hoc notation. In this book, `num` is a built-in type which would correspond to e.g. `Integer` of Haskell (not `Num` and not `num`).

Comment: @Carl Apologies for the confusion, the essence of the question wasn't clear. It is trivial to create a function of type (a -> a) -> a as I have done but the question specifically substitutes a for num suggesting that a polymorphic type will not do. What num represents does not matter, just that it is a defined type and not "any type a". num could be Integer, Boolean, or any other self-defined type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is enough to give a function which *can be assigned that type*, then yours is already enough. That is, the following type-checks just fine:

```
func1 :: Num a => (a -> a) -> a
func1 f = f 3
```

If, on the other hand, you want a function which *is inferred to have that type*, then you need to do some trickery. What we want to do here is to specify that the result of `f 3` and the `3` that we fed in have the same type. The standard way to force two terms to have the same type is to use `asTypeOf`, which is implemented this way:

```
asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a
asTypeOf x _ = x
```

So let's try:

```
> :t \f -> f 3 `asTypeOf` 3
(Num a, Num t) => (t -> a) -> a
```

Unfortunately for us, this doesn't work, because the `3` in `f 3` and the standalone `3` are inferred to be using *potentially different* instances of `Num`. Still, it is a bit closer than `\f -> f 3` was -- note the new `Num a` constraint on the output that we didn't have before. An obvious next idea is to `let`-bind a variable to `3` and reuse that variable as the argument to both `f` and `asTypeOf`; surely then GHC will get the picture that `f`'s argument and result have the same type, right?

```
> :t \f -> let x = 3 in f x `asTypeOf` x
(Num a, Num t) => (t -> a) -> a
```

Drat. Turns out that `let`s do what's called "let generalization"; the `x` will be just as polymorphic as the `3` was, and can be specialized to different types at different use sites. Usually this is a nice feature, but because we're doing an unnatural exercise we need to do unnatural things...

Okay, next idea: some lambda calculi do not include a `let`, and when you need one, instead of writing `let a = b in c`, you write `(\a -> c) b`. This is especially interesting for us because Haskell uses a specially-restricted kind of polymorphism that means that inside `c`, the type of `a` is *monomorphic*. So:

```
> :t \f -> (\x -> f x `asTypeOf` x) 3
Num a => (a -> a) -> a
```

And now you complain that `asTypeOf` is cheating, because it uses a type declaration that doesn't match its inferred type, and the whole point of the exercise was to get the right type through inference alone. (If we were okay with using type declarations that don't match the inferred type, we could have stopped at `func1 :: Num a => (a -> a) -> a; func1 f = f 3` from way back at the beginning!) Okay, no problem: there's another standardish way to force the types of two expressions to unify, namely, by putting them in a list together. So:

```
> :t \f -> (\x -> head [f x, x]) 3
Num a => (a -> a) -> a
```

Phew, now we're finally at a place where we could in principle build, from the ground up, all the tools needed to get a term of the right type without any type declarations.

Comment: Another idea: `\f -> f (f 1)`

Answer (score 0):

`func1 f = let x = f x in x` This is a partial function, it technically has the type you want and you should be aware of what they are and how they work in haskell.

Comment: That is the fix point function. It has the structure of what is being asked but it is not (num -> num) -> num it is identified in GHCi as (t -> t) -> t